# Trying to use groupby function twice and then find the max?

Tags: python, pandas

I have election data from 1976 to 2020 and I am attempting to find the party that won each state individually for each year. That, is I'm looking for 1976 Alabama Winner (such as republican, democrat, etc). Also, in the dataframe I have votes by candidate and total votes. So I'm trying to extract each winner by grouping by state, grouping by year, then taking the maximum votes to find the winner and delete everything else. (so final df should have 240 items). Is this even possible? Here is my code so far: In which I get the key error: state.

It's not a capitalization issue, and there is a column labeled 'state' so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd     # import the pandas library to read a .csv file
import numpy as np      # use py for numpy from now on
import seaborn as sns
data = pd.read_csv('1976-2020-president.csv')
winner = data.groupby('year').groupby('state').max['totalvotes']
```

Comment: winner = data.groupby(['year','state']).max['totalvotes']

Comment: Oh that did fix it! Further question, I have another column called 'party_simplified' that I want to be displayed when I run it (so I know what political party won each state). How do I incorporate it? I tried adding it with year and state but then I just got all the data and not just the maximum value (aka the winner)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet to group by `year` and `state`, and then find the `max` value of `totalvotes`:

```
winner = data.groupby(['year','state'])['totalvotes'].max()
```